# What happened to the dhelp package?

Tags: documentation, html

Previously, I happened to consult local HTML documentation under
`/usr/share/doc/HTML/` which should be available after installing the `dhelp` package.

However, since running Xubuntu LTS 14.04, this very `dhelp` package can no longer be installed. Does anybody know why?

PS: The package `dwww` is available. However, I do not want to be installing an Apache server just for this.

```
$ dhelp
The program 'dhelp' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install dhelp

$ sudo apt-get install dhelp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package dhelp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dhelp' has no installation candidate

$ dpkg -l dhelp
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                               Version                Architecture           Description
+++-==================================-======================-======================-==========================================================================
un  dhelp                              <none>                 <none>                 (no description available)
```

Comment: [Edit] your question an add the output of `apt-cache policy dwww`

Answer (score 1):

The package `dhelp` hasn't been available since Trusty: You could:

1. Try to install the Precise version, but I don't have Trusty in order to test that, sorry **;)**

   ```
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dhelp/dhelp_0.6.20ubuntu1_all.deb
   sudo dpkg -i dhelp_0.6.20ubuntu1_all.deb
   ```
2. Try to install `dwww` without installing `apache2`: It's possible to force the installation of `dwww` without the dependencies, but it's something else I'm not willing to test on my system neither, sorry!

   ```
   apt-get download dwww
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all dwww_1.12.1_amd64.deb
   ```

So better take a system backup before you try any of the above *workarounds*...  **;-)**